# What is the point of having multiple file descriptors to the same file?

Tags: file-descriptor

I was surprised to see that we can have different file descriptors to the same file. My question is simply: What is the point of doing this? I would expect it to error in some way or perhaps it could return the same file descriptor. I understand why not the latter but I don't understand why my first expectation is not the case.

I'm getting this behavior with NASM; although I have seen other questions saying that it is also the behavior with some C functions, without further discussion on why we can/should.

Comment: If you have a large program with different libraries in them doing things, wouldn't it be really inconvenient to get an error every time one part of the program tries to open a file another part has already open?  That said, a file descriptor keeps track of a file pointer.  If you want multiple pointers into the same file, you need multiple file descriptors (or use `pread` and `pwrite`).

Comment: Suppose two users open the same shared file?  Or suppose the same user opens the same file in two different programs?  If these things are allowed, then it actually becomes more work to prevent the same program opening the same file.  That is, why would you add in extra code in the kernel to detect and disallow this?

Comment: Also, this is not connected to assembly or nasm or x86 or any of the other random (?) tags you added.  This behaviour is copied in all unix-like operating systems no matter what language or compiler you use.  It is part of the basic definition of the OS model.

Comment: @TomV (to both of your comments) I thought that a language or a programmer themself could implement some sort of structure (associative array?) that would 
store data to return the same file descriptor, but that would be quite useless now that I 
better understand how file descriptors work.